# How can I access another extension's greeting using RingCentral?

Tags: ringcentral

I am having trouble referencing one extension's custom greeting to another extension. Is the only way to set custom greetings (including `HoldMusic` and `ConnectingAudio`) via the Update Greeting API:

`POST /restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/{extensionId}/greeting/{greetingId}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RingCentral doesn't support shared greetings right now, so you will need to update the greeting for each extension. If this is a big issue, please let us know and we can consider it as an enhancement.